# How to force reload only some sources in Chrome/Firefox

Tags: django, google-chrome, firefox, web-applications

I’m developing a web application written in Django, I’m running the server in my machine  and use Chrome/Firefox to view and test the website. I want to be able to work on it while I’m on a plane/tube and I don’t have internet.

Now, the HTML loads some resources from the local server but some others from external CDNs. I want to work on some js and css files that are hosted on my machine and view the changes in the browser, so I have to force reload the website since chrome by default just shows the cached versions of these, but if I force reload, then ALL sources are reloaded and the CDN sources obviously fail to be fetched (and my site looks horrible).

So I want to know how I can reload (in Chrome or Firefox) only some of the sources of my site and still use the cached versions of the CDN ones (assume these are cached because I load them before going into the plane).

Any help or advise on how other people would solve this would be much appreciated.

Comment: One idea is to use [Django Compressor](https://django-compressor.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage/). So what you can do is to put the css files which you want to load from local file in compressor template block.
Another way is to use external tools like webpack to produce unique name per compressed css files.
But there is a downside for these solutions, as css will be compressed, it will be really hard to debug.

Comment: @ruddra interesting suggestion, though as you say not great for debugging purposes. I may give it a go